# Can't click link requiring authentication in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webautomation

I have a situation that seems specific to Firefox that I'm encountering during my web testing.

I login to my test site using parameters included to the URL:

```
https://testlogin:testsite@www.site.com/
```

The page which loads has a clickable link which requires the login and password delivered via the URL.

Once the page has loaded, I am unable to click the link; it does not look like the page has received the login and password specified in the URL.

I've the following click methods.

- driver.click
- driver.tap

I have only been able to reproduce this problem with Firefox. Thanks in advance.

```
p driver.find_element(:css, ' > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a').displayed?

driver.find_element(:css, ' > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a').click
```

Console throws me an error

***SecurityError: The operation is insecure.***

Comment: Can you provide some sample code so that we see what you're doing?

Comment: just a simple click

Comment: Which framework do you use? Please add this and a code sample to your question, not to a comment

Comment: I'm using selenium  webdriver

Comment: Please add this and a code sample to your question, not to a comment